# Cómo poner 2 imágenes en el centro de una página web?

Tags: css, bootstrap, web

Estoy tratando hacer una página de inicio con 2 imágenes, una te lleva a una sección de la web y la otra a otra, pero no logro hacer algo como esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estas usando css puro, o algun framework en especifico

Comment: Hola! ¿Podrías incluir el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: Soy nuevo en esto de crear webs, no uso ningún framework solo la librería de bootstrap

Comment: @Ragnaval por favor edita tu pregunta para añadir más detalles: ¿qué versión de bootstrap usas? ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿cómo ha fallado lo que has intentado? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap te permite utilizar su sistema de posicionamiento grid, es fantastico... y consiste en crear Filas horizontales, y esas filas dividirlas en columnas, lo que necesitas ahora es una fila horizontal que divida en columnas para colocar 2 imagenes, vamos con el codigo.
Te dejo la documentacion
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Lo que hace este codigo es crear una fila horizontal llamada row, y dividirla en columnas col-sm.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

El tamaño máximo de columnaje es 12, por lo que cada row puede tener hasta 12 columnas...
para este caso tuyo podrías utilizar este codigo y modificarlo.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <!--margen navegador izquierdo-->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      Foto 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      Foto2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1">
      <!--margen navegador derecho-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

aplicando una columna vertical al principio y al final aplicaremos los margenes... y dando 5 y 5 a cada imagen le daremos espacio para colocar las imagenes en esas columnas en total sumando 12, puedes insertar otra columna entre las fotos para darles margen entre ellas... y aplicando a las img este estilo las puedes centrar en su columna

```
img{
    text-align:center
}
```

y no tiene mucho más, consulta la documentación y haz pruebas, cualquier duda puedes responder, un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con esto:

La estructura HTML consiste en una primera div ajustada a la pantalla, la cual contiene otra div que contendrá las imágenes y que podrás disponer como quieras en la div raíz. En este caso centrada y con margen laterales.

Las reglas de CSS son esencialmente de ajuste al ancho y alto de la pantalla para la clase *screen*, y de posición y centrado para la clase *img-container*.

Así, la clase por defecto *img* dispone las imagenes centradas horizontalmente siempre que el ancho sea mayor que el ancho total de las imágenes.

```css
/* CSS */
.screen{
  background: red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.img-container{
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(100vw - 120px);
  height: auto;
}

img{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="screen">DIV1
  <div class="img-container">DIV2
    <img src="https://tcprd-tdcdn.netdna-ssl.com/blue-silk-texture-solid-knit-skinny-tie-250713-400-100-0.jpg">
    <img src="https://tcprd-tdcdn.netdna-ssl.com/blue-silk-texture-solid-knit-skinny-tie-250713-400-100-0.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ooops, edito mi respuesta ¡disculpad!